# Issue with apache rewrite rule course 500 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have website build in custom CMS, and when we tried to change hosting it gives me 500 error. I realize that it is caused by this like in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule .* phps/i.php [L]
```

On Apache log I did notice next result:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
>   configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the
>   limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

I tried to use `RewriteBase` but it did not work.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: This is the most common error with mod rewrite. Your `.*` matches everything, including `i.php` and causes a rewrite loop. There are many many examples around this site, but most commonly the solution is to first place `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` so the rewrite is only applied to requests that aren't real files.

Comment: Otherwise `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !phps/i\.php` to just exclude that file from the rewrite.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
RewriteRule !phps/i\.php phps/i.php [L]
```

Comment: Yes, that help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions. One of them: put .htaccess file with one line "RewriteEngine Off" into phps/

Comment: Sorry, but that's a little useless, I need to have it on

Comment: The end of my answer has been losed. It was "into phps/"